# JavaScript For Loop Not getting the access to parentElement Of Input type(checkbox)

Tags: javascript

I try my best to find my answer on google but fail.So please help me.
I am creating checkboxes and i want that when these checkboxes are checked/clicked,then the background of their parent element (which is label) should be change.
when i test with a single checkbox, it is working good .for example

```js
var check = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox')[0];
check.onchange = function() {
 if(check.checked ===true) {
  check.parentElement.style.background="lightblue";
  }else 
  check.parentElement.style.background="white";
 };
```

```html
<label style="width: 100px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid black;">
<input type="checkbox"  name="jpeg" class="checkbox" value="Jpeg"/>Jpeg</label>
```

But When using "for" Loop for multiple chekcboxes .... It is showing error that ""can not read property of undefined" 
for example ..

```js
var check = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
var i;
for(i=0; i < check.length; i++) {
check[i].onchange = function() {
 if(check[i].checked ===true) {
  check[i].parentElement.style.background="lightblue";
  }else 
  check[i].parentElement.style.background="white";
 };
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" id="1" name="jpeg" class="checkbox" value="Jpeg"/>Jpeg</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="1" name="jpeg" class="checkbox" value="Jpeg"/>Jpeg</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="1" name="jpeg" class="checkbox" value="Jpeg"/>Jpeg</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Don't use a variable*** for the element. Use `this` in the handler to reference the bound element instead.

Also, the handler code can be shortened using the conditional operator.

```js
var check = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
  check[i].onchange = handler;
}

function handler() {
  this.parentElement.style.background = this.checked ? "lightblue" : "white";
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" id="1" name="jpeg" class="checkbox" value="Jpeg"/>Jpeg</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="1" name="jpeg" class="checkbox" value="Jpeg"/>Jpeg</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="1" name="jpeg" class="checkbox" value="Jpeg"/>Jpeg</label>
```

---

Also, if all you need to do is change the background, and if you can rework the markup to put the label alongside the checkbox, then ***just use CSS***.

```css
label {
  background-color: white;
}
.checkbox:checked + label {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="1" name="jpeg" class="checkbox" value="Jpeg"/><label for=1>Jpeg</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="jpeg" class="checkbox" value="Jpeg"/><label for=2>Jpeg</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="3" name="jpeg" class="checkbox" value="Jpeg"/><label for=3>Jpeg</label>
```

Comment: @kashifRiaz: You're welcome. I also added a CSS-only solution. But for sure, don't use a variable an definitely not an IIFE. They're missing out on the most obvious solution based on how handlers are meant to work.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this ;)

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(event){
  const element = event.target;
  if(element.className === 'checkbox'){
       element.parentNode.style.background= element.checked ? "lightblue" : "white";
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You code did not work because of the scoping of the `var` keyword. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)(Cleaner code in inner functions paragraph) you can find the detailed explanation of your problem. Essentially you can solve that in 2 ways.

First:

```
var check = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');

for(let i=0; i < check.length; i++) {
check[i].onchange = function() {
 if(check[i].checked ===true) {
  check[i].parentElement.style.background="lightblue";
  }else 
  check[i].parentElement.style.background="white";
 };
}
```

Second:

```
var check = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');

for(var i=0; i < check.length; i++) {
(function(index){
    check[index].onchange = function() {
      if(check[index].checked ===true) {
        check[index].parentElement.style.background="lightblue";
      }else 
        check[index].parentElement.style.background="white";
    };
})(i);
}
```